# Velocity and Time Elapsed in sfml 2.0

Tags: c++, character, velocity, sfml

So I have been looking for hours now and I can't seem to find anything to help me with this, so I'll start by saying I am new, like very new, but I do understand that in order to have constant move speed at varying framerates I need to incorporate velocity and determine the time elapsed since the last iteration of the loop.

So this is what I have so far

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "Oliver Rules!");

float speed = 20.f;
float locX = 0.f;
float locY = 0.f;

sf::CircleShape circleOne(50);
circleOne.setFillColor(sf::Color(200, 40, 200));

sf::Clock clock;


while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }



    sf::Time elapsed1 = clock.restart();

    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
        {
            locX -= speed * elapsed1;
        }
    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
        {
            locX += 0.1;
        }
    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
        {
            locY -= 0.1;
        }
    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
        {
            locY += 0.1;
        }


    circleOne.setPosition(locX, locY);
    circleOne.move(locX, locY);


    window.clear();
    window.draw(circleOne);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

What my problem is, is that I can not add or subtract from the variables I have initiated to be the location of my circleOne can not be edited due to the elapsed1 being a float I believe, so my question is, how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `speed` and `elapsed1` are not the same type. One is `float` while the other is `sf::Time`. If you want `locX -= speed * elapsed1` to work, you will have to transform `elapsed1` to `float`.

In order to do that, you can used the methods `elapsed1.asSeconds`, `elapsed1.asMilliseconds` and `elapsed1.asMicroseconds`, depending on the kind of units you want.

If you want to know more about that, you should have a look at the [SFML 2.0 documentation for `sf::Time`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Time.php).

Comment: Ah sweet I thought I had to convert the elapsed but I couldn't figure out how, thanks a million :)

Comment: Apparently I can't upvote yet :( however I couldnt get it to work this is what I put in, I don't think I am doing it write and I have read that documentation before, I understand what I need to do but not how to. Its okay though I'll figure this part out :) thanks heaps for the help.

Comment: @user2342575 Ok, no problem then. Hope you will have fun with SFML 2.0 :)

Comment: Lol thanks heaps, just to finish it off I got it, I didn't realise you had to type the code like this   float elapsed = clock.restart().asSeconds(); I was writing it like this,    float elapsed = asSeconds(clock.restart());